# Not able to require modules from the sub directory [ react-native ]

Tags: react-native

So I have my first react-native project to start.
I created a project structure as a separate folder per module.
So it looks something like

```
index.ios.js
package.json
+ios
+app
  +auth
     login.js
     signup.js
```

In login.js I am exporting my component using `module.exports = LoginBox`

And in index.ios.js i am requiring `LoginBox = require('./app/auth/login.js')`

Now on compiling I am getting error in simulator "Unable to resolve module ./app/auth/login.js. Invalid Directory [App root]/app/auth/login.js .

But if I am keeping my login.js directly inside app folder and requiring like `LoginBox = require('./app/login.js')` , it works perfectly.

I don't know what exact problem is and it completely feels weird to me. Is there something I should follow ?

**UPDATE:**

Not sure why it happened but worked properly after reinitializing app.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Try restarting the packager?

Comment: everlasto - exact incantation please?